# error in specific table migration laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

I want to run just one migration file, when I use

```
$php artisan migrate  --path=/database/migrations/2019_03_20_101338_create_calendars_table.php
```

I get this error

> Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::requireOnce(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project/C:/Program Files/Git/database/migrations/2019_03_20_10
> 1338_create_calendars_table.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: Try it with the following path: ``--path=database/migrations/2019_03_20_101338_create_calendars_table.php``
So remove the first slash right infront of "database".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the first slash from the URI, the first slash means the URI is absolute instead of a relative one.

`$php artisan migrate  --path=database/migrations/2019_03_20_101338_create_calendars_table.php`

Comment: Your comment was not present when I posted my anwer. Anyway I'm sorry if I offended you.